# Unity read from http

Tags: http, unity-game-engine

I have:

```
public TextAsset ttt;
void OnGUI(){

GUI.TextArea(new Rect(600,10,350,300),ttt.text,style_text);
}
```

I already have hosting anf file txt http://host.com/fff.txt

My question is: how can I read this file online and put in TextArea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use WWW to do so

```
public string GetHTML(string uri){
       WWW www = new WWW (uri);     
       while (!www.isDone)  //wait until www isdone
            ;

       if (www.error != null) 
            return null;        
       return www.text;}
```

Above is simple code for you,for more, see also http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.html

In fact you can use WWW to get text/texture/audio from web/filepath, I'm sure you can handle after read that manual :)

---

TextArea: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GUI.TextArea.html

As you want display a text, AKA UI, I suggest you leave Unity GUI alone. Generally, for now, if you want to develop quality games quickly, Unity GUI system ain't your best choice, it's waste time somewhat. You may take a look to NGUI(http://www.tasharen.com/?page_id=140), most people use it(or maybe iGUI, fastGUI etc) on products, not that native one.

With NGUI, you can create a UILabel widget/component, and call `UILabel.text = "SomeString"`.

Comment: I would advise against using a while loop to check `www.isDone`, that will block your entire game.  Instead use `yield www`, like the documentation you link states.

Comment: indeed, I do it for handy :p bad one